# php checking array values

Tags: php, arrays

Hey all i am trying to figure out a way to see what all values are within the array:

```
  $sql = "select * from product where type = ? limit 1";
$query = self::$__CONN__->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array($type)) or die(print_r($query->errorinfo()));
```

I am new at PHP and im not sure what all that is doing to populate the query string. I am guessing that the first query is connecting to the server and sending out the query but how do i see what its returning back in the array above?

Any help would be great!

Comment: What is `$type` supposed to be?

Comment: You mean you want to assign the result to an array and `echo` the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just dump the $type variable

```
var_dump($type);
```

Or if you are interested in the array wrapper itself

```
var_dump(array($type));
```